# thread.join() not consequent

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm working with threads, the worker function is the following:

```
void threadDoIt(tso* tso0){
    while (true){
        task t = tso0->getNextTask();
        if (t.getState() == empty){
            break;
        }
        else {
            t.execute();
            TAL::taskExecuted(t);
        }
    }
}

/*...*/

vector<thread> threads;

for (int i = 0; i < cpus; i++){
    threads.push_back(thread(threadDoIt, tsos.at(i)));
}

for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++){
    threads[i].join();
}
```

and I experience that sometimes all the tasks are executed, but sometimes not. It seems like there's a problem with the joining method. Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean are not executed? They start but never finish? Or they never start? Perhaps there's a syncing problem in `getNextTask` (deadlocks, for example)?

Comment: Can you create a [short, self contained, correct example](http://www.sscce.org/)? This code depends on a few outside factors that might be causing the problem.